# Resign First Responder Using a Search Bar

Tags: ios, xcode

I have created a UI Search Bar in my .xib and connected it to the delegate and also hooked it up to the .h file/.m file. I want to know if it is possible to dismiss the keyboard just from hitting the return key while typing into the search bar.  I know how to do this with a text field, but I cannot seem to make it happen with the search bar.

Any help is appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Make sure your uisearchbar is connected to your view delegate.

After that go to .h file and include UISearcBarDelegate

Then go to .m file and implement this code

```
 -(void)searchBarSearchButtonClicked:(UISearchBar *)searchBar {

    [self.yourSearchBar resignFirstResponder];

 }
```

hope helps...